# Postgresql error when reverse geocoding in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, reverse-geocoding

I am having an issue trying to do a bulk reverse geocode using the geocoder rails gem: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

I have the following models:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude

  has_one :address
end
```

and

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
end
```

And the following migrations:

```
class CreateSchools < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :schools do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :address_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.string :line_1
      t.string :line_2
      t.string :line_3
      t.string :city
      t.string :region
      t.string :country
      t.string :code

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and when I run the following line:
`rake geocode:all CLASS=School REVERSE=true SLEEP=0.5`

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column schools.address does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "schools".* FROM "schools" WHERE (schools.address IS...
                                                  ^
: SELECT  "schools".* FROM "schools" WHERE (schools.address IS NULL)  ORDER BY "schools"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
```

I know the readme says this:

> "For geocoding your model must provide a method that returns an
>   address. This can be a single attribute, but it can also be a method
>   that returns a string assembled from different attributes (eg: city,
>   state, and country)."

I took that to mean I needed either a method on the School model or the attribute on the school table and I opted for the latter but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the reverse-geocoding rake task starts by loading all the records with no address column yet. It uses [this scope](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/e9d7100009ff7be15a9d5a3e7578ceee0e047bb4/lib/geocoder/stores/active_record.rb#L32-L34):

```
scope :not_reverse_geocoded, lambda {
  where("#{table_name}.#{geocoder_options[:fetched_address]} IS NULL")
}
```

The problem is you don't have any column on `schools` you could use. Instead, you should move the `reverse_geocoded_by` declaration to the `Address` class. You will also need to either add an `addresses.address` column or do something like this:

```
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude, fetched_address: :line_1
```

Also you don't seem to have columns for `latitude` and `longitude`. And of course those should be on `Address` too, not `School`. After all, if a school can have several addresses, which one is its lonlat?

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification!